# Custom Shopify Add to Cart Button

Tags: jquery, if-statement, e-commerce, shopping-cart, shopify

I have a custom size chart in my Shopify Store and when someone clicks on the size they want and then click the Add to Cart button I would like to have that size be added to the cart. However, right now I am unsure how I can accomplish this. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<div class="sizes">
  {{ 'size-triangle.png' | asset_url | img_tag }} 
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
    <a href="#" class="size-btn {{ variant.title }}-product {% if variant.inventory_quantity == 0 %}outofstock{% endif %} {% if variant.title contains 'OS'%}hide{% endif %}" data-quantity="{{ variant.available }}" data-id="{{ variant.id }}" data-size="{{ variant.title }}">{{ variant.title }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

<div id="product-add">
   <input class="button" type="submit" name="add" value="Add to cart" id="purchase">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [Line Item Properties](http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/products/how-do-I-collect-additional-information-on-the-product-page-Like-for-a-monogram-engraving-or-customization) is what you are looking for:

> **Line Item Properties** are used to collect customization information about an item when it is added to the cart.
>   ...
>   Shopify looks for form fields that have a name attribute set to `properties[ANYTHING]`.

E.g.

```
<input type="text" id="monogram" name="properties[Monogram]" />
```